# Challenges in migrating application from fastify to express in nestjs

Tags: express, nestjs, fastify

I'm trying to choose between express and fastify along with nestjs for my backend. At the moment I'm more inclined towards fastify as it offers superior speed and ease of use. But I have a question in mind specifically: Say 4 months into the project, my complicated fastify application for whatever reason is giving low performance and if I were to migrate to express how expensive will that be?

From what I understand the majority of the challenge will be in:

- Controller and
- Middleware

Is there anything that I should think about...? I appreciate any response in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think, I understand now. NestJs is platform independent i.e we can migrate between express and fastify quite easily and most of the implementation remains same. Basically we have to keep in mind that when we use FastifyAdapter, nest uses fastify as http provider and so we will have to install fastify based packages if we choose fastify, or express equivalent when we choose express. I would appreciate if someone can review my remark.